# Changing the log.dir path for Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm looking to change the log.dirs path for all Kafka log data that will be held on the broker servers however i already have a handful number of existing topics created and actively being used but not sure what will happen to the existing topic/log data? Can someone please clarify what would be the impact on the existing topics/log data by changing the log.dirs log path? Thanks

Comment: Surely it's as simple as creating a new directory somewhere else on the file system and providing a simlink to that location, if nothing else can be done by changing the broker configuration?

Answer (score 1):

They'd be untracked, not be cleaned with retention/compaction, and when the server restarts, the clients would be unable to read that data anymore.

It'd be better to stop the broker, copy/move all the log files to the new location, then change the config, and start the broker.

Comment: Awesome, many thanks for the response @OneCricketeer. Is it just matter of copying/moving the log files onto new location and changing the log.dirs value followed by rolling restart of the BR servers? Is there any other attributes/values that i need to change which i might have not think of? I'm just taking a little bit of precaution before doing this change as we don't want to break the existing topic data/logs! We do have a set of ACL authorizations against these topics in place and i hope they wouldn't be affected by this change?

Comment: Sounds right. Cannot think of other props. ACLs are stored in Zookeeper, unless you have some other implementation of that

Comment: Hey, i did follow the instructions you mentioned in sequence. The BR servers got restarted successfully and picked up the new log.dirs path, however post changes i cannot see any of the topics and when i try to do a list --topics it returns nothing! Sadly none of the clients are able to read/write data onto the old topics! The logs are all found to be intact in the new directory path but the BR/ZK just cannot list/find the topics! Not sure what's missing! How do i view the topic metadata and the ACL datastores on Zookeeper servers? Is there a directory which holds all of the ZK database?

Comment: Also to add - the log.dirs path was changed not only on the broker servers, but also on the Zookeepers by amending the dataDir attribute/value. The ZK service is up & running and it's also picked up the new directory path but just can't list/find any topics!

Comment: Hmm. I believe, the only interaction is check ZK to `/topics/{topic}` Znode. Yes, `dataDir` stores the Znode data on disk. Then a client request is made to the broker `{log.dirs}/{topic}-{partition}` based on the partitions stored in the Znode. There shouldn't be any other relation to topic storage locations, but I could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you and tried the simlink solution that I suggested in the comments.

Perhaps unsurprisingly it does work.

For example, if your Kafka cluster specifies the log dir to be `/opt/kafka/log` you might consider moving the contents of `/opt/kafka/log/kraft-combined-logs` to some other directory on your machine which lives on a different physical disk. (This is what I have just done.)

Then create your simlink to that new directory.

```
ln -s /mnt/md0/kafka/kraft-combined-logs /opt/kafka/logs/kraft-combined-logs
```

If you are not using Kraft, your log directory might be in a different location.

Also note that I have only moved the topic data, which lives inside `kraft-combined-logs`. The directory `/opt/kafka/log` also contains other files which are important to Kafka operation. You might want to move those as well, by moving the higher level directory `/opt/kafka/log`.

I am surprised that you can't simply move the whole `/opt/kafka/log` and then change the configuration of Kafka to let it know the log directory is now somewhere else, but OneCricketer is usually pretty solid on Kafka knowledge, so I will trust his response on this.